# Using infinity in dynamic programming coins example - why does this not fail?

Tags: python, dynamic-programming

been trying to understand how to use dynamic programming on this page

https://www.topcoder.com/community/data-science/data-science-tutorials/dynamic-programming-from-novice-to-advanced/

Given a list of N coins, their values (V1, V2, … , VN), and the total sum S. Find the minimum number of coins the sum of which is S (we can use as many coins of one type as we want), or report that it’s not possible to select coins in such a way that they sum up to S.

Given coins with values 1, 3, and 5.
And the sum S is set to be 11.

```
Set Min[i] equal to Infinity for all of i
Min[0]=0

For i = 1 to S
For j = 0 to N - 1
   If (Vj<=i AND Min[i-Vj]+1<Min[i])
Then Min[i]=Min[i-Vj]+1

Output Min[S]
```

I am confused as to why we are setting infinity for all of i.

even more confusing is when the sum is 1

```
If (Vj<=i AND Min[i-Vj]+1<Min[i])
```

wouldn't Min[1] be undefined? wouldn't the code fail here? and why are they adding +1??

or will it continue because is it infinite? Why are they using infinite here? And what is `N-1` where did they get it from?

Overall I found their explanation very hard to follow.

Comment: any number is less than infinity so a pretty safe place to start with a default value

Comment: how would you write that in code, that something is to be infinite? I know its infinite but wondering how you would avoid running into undefined error here.

Comment: You could use `float("inf")`

Comment: `Set Min[i] equal to Infinity for all of i` how would you write that in python?

Comment: Are you sure this is python? It doesn't seem to be.

Comment: @RichL It isn't python.  It appears to be pseudocode, probably from a textbook on dynamic optimization.

Comment: you are right it is pseudo code but im trying to figure out how i can write the python code for it

Comment: Hint:  Min[1] is the minimum number of coins to achieve value sum S=1, Min[2] is the minimum number of coins to achieve value sum S=2, etc...

Comment: This looks like a similar problem, with python code: http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/pythonds/Recursion/DynamicProgramming.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is hopefully a direct translation:

```
def dp_coin(S, coins):
    # set all values to infinity in range S/sum needed
    mn = [float("inf") for j in range(S+1)]
    # takes 0 coins to sum 0
    mn[0] = 0
    # start at second index 1
    for i in range(1, S+1):
        for j in range(len(coins)):
            if coins[j] <= i and mn[i-coins[j]]+1 < mn[i]:
                mn[i] = mn[i-coins[j]] + 1
    return mn[-1]

print(dp_coin(11, [1, 3, 5]))
3
```

If you print mn you will see:

```
[0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3]
```

which is the same as the table:

```
Sum Min. nr. of coins   Coin value added to a smaller sum to
obtain this sum (it is displayed in brackets)
0   0   -
1   1   1 (0)
2   2   1 (1)
3   1   3 (0)
4   2   1 (3)
5   1   5 (0)
6   2   3 (3)
7   3   1 (6)
8   2   3 (5)
9   3   1 (8)
10  2   5 (5)
11  3   1 (10)
```

`S` refers to the total sum required, `coins[j]` is equivalent to `Vj`, `N` was referring to coins.

The inner loop can be removed and simply iterate over coins:

```
def dp_coin(S, coins):
    mn = [float("inf") for j in range(S+1)]
    mn[0] = 0
    for i in range(1, S+1):
        for j in coins:
            if j <= i and mn[i-j]+1 < mn[i]:
                mn[i] = mn[i-j] + 1
    return mn[-1]
```

Comment: but why did they do `+1` ? `  if j <= i and mn[i-j]+1 < mn[i]:
                mn[i] = mn[i-j] + 1` and how did you know that `N-1` is `S+1` ?

Comment: `i+1` is the next state, `N-1` is coins not `S`, we need S+1 because ranges are not inclusive